# Combine credit card cash back with other cash back offer

Tags: credit-card, cash

At this [website](http://www.fatwallet.com/learn-more/what-is-cash-back/)

you can buy gift cards and get cash back. Now I have a credit card that gives 1% cash back. If I use it to purchase a gift card here, will i get 1% back from credit card and on top the cash back offered by the site? Or is there a 'Offer not valid with any other promotion' lurking somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in picture. I tried using FatWallet site and used Gift Card mall Vendor for purchase. 
Only restriction they have is I can not purchase Visa Gift Card and some other vendors.

Please verify each vendors Policy on purchase and restrictions.

and I believe, on your credit card as long as you purchase something you get 1% back as long as its not restricted to grocery, gas, restaurant or movies only.

Enjoy Shopping

[image: FatWallet_GiftCardMall]

Answer (score 0):

The "cash back" from your card is from your bank, to encourage you to use the card.

The "cash back" from the site you mentioned is from the site, who are being paid more than that by the stores to get you to commit money to them. It's basically a variant on a manufacturer's coupon, pure advertising.

The two are unrelated. There's no reason for them to exclude each other, so they don't.

Of course you have to decide whether either of these bits of bait is worth what it costs you in higher rate or fees on the credit card, or in locking yourself into a particular store on the discounting site.